# How to count columns for every file after unzipping a folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to unzip a folder and take the count of the files that exist in the folder and check the file count =32 else send an email with present file names and execute the infacmds for present files and wait for 32 conditions to satisfy.

In this script I want to check the file count and also the column count for the existing files and if the column count -neq 280 it has to send email error.

where the column code is like this, which i have to introduce in main code :

```
$columnCount = ( ( Get-Content "C:\Users\xs15169\Desktop\temp\OEC2_CFLOW.txt" | Select-Object -First 1 ) -Split ',' ).Count
echo "Column count is: $columnCount"
```

The below code which I have tried(#looks for a file with below type format .zip and it will unzip the files and will take count):

```
#unzip commands will be here
#LogWrite "Starting of process"
Function LogWrite
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $log -value "$(Get-Date) $logstring"
}

  try { 
   LogWrite "Start unzipping $zipfilename"
   Remove-Item $unzipfolderdelete | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
    #Unzip $zipfilename $unzipfolder

    Set-Alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

    sz x $zipfilename -o"$unzipfolder" -y
    LogWrite "$zipfilename unzipped to $unzipfolder successfully"
    $filecount= (dir $unzipfolder | measure).Count
    if ($filecount -eq 32)
    {
        #LogWrite "File Count 32


        #LogWrite "Executed informatica scripts for condition filecount equal to 32"
        #LogWrite "End of if"
    }
    elseif ($filecount -ne 0)
    {

        LogWrite "File Count " + $filecount
        $list = Get-ChildItem $unzipfolder
        $incompletefilenames =""
        ForEach($n in $list){

        $incompletefilenames = $incompletefilenames + $n.Name + "<br>`n"

        }

        LogWrite $incompletefilenames
        LogWrite "Sending email for filecount not equal to 32"

            $Params = @{ 
               email setup
            }
            Send-MailMessage @Params
            LogWrite "Successfully emailed available file names"

        #Execute Informatica scripts


        LogWrite "Executed informatica scripts for condition filecount not equal to 32"
         LogWrite "End of elseif"
    }
    else
    {
         LogWrite "File Count " + $filecount
             $Params = @{ 
                email setup
            }
            Send-MailMessage @Params
          LogWrite "End of else"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you must have some paths figured out.

Try this:

```
Set-Alias sz "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

$zipFile = "C:\temp\10 yard Fight.zip"

# Get Name of file without extension or path
$zipFolderToCreate = (gci $zipFile).BaseName

# Get path of zip
$path = (gci $zipFile).Directory.FullName

sz x -o"$path\*" "$zipFile"  -r

$filecount= (dir "$path\$zipFolderToCreate" | measure).Count
```